# How to let clang-format format c++ long for loop into three lines?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want any *long* for-loop to automatically be broken into three lines; like:

```
    for (auto origin = backup_to_origins[peer].begin();
         origin != backup_to_origins[peer].end(); 
         origin++)
```

But clang-format of google style format it into two lines:

```
    for (auto origin = backup_to_origins[peer].begin();
         origin != backup_to_origins[peer].end(); origin++)
```

The `BinPackArguments` option splits every for-loop into three lines, including short ones, which is not what I want.

Based on line width, I only want loops that take up greater than `X` amount of chars to be broken up into three lines. Loops that are <= `X` chars, they can stay on one line. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have the exact same question. Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `BinPackArguments` didn't work for you. Perhaps you have other style options set? Perhaps an earlier (or later?) version of clang-format works differently? I used clang-format 6.0.0 to verify the behavior in this answer.

I get exactly what you're asking for with this:

```
BinPackArguments: false
```

For example, given myfile.cpp containing this:

```
int f()
{
    for (auto origin = backup_to_origins[peer].begin();
         origin != backup_to_origins[peer].end(); 
         origin++)
    {
    }
    for (auto o = b.begin();
         o != b.end();
         o++)
    {
    }
}
```

The command line `clang-format -style='{BasedOnStyle: Google,BinPackArguments: false}' myfile.cpp` produces this output:

```
int f() {
  for (auto origin = backup_to_origins[peer].begin();
       origin != backup_to_origins[peer].end();
       origin++) {
  }
  for (auto o = b.begin(); o != b.end(); o++) {
  }
}
```

The line length `X` you refer to is controlled by the `ColumnLimit` style option, which normally defaults to 80.

See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more details on these style options.